# WebStorm can not detect Android SDK in path

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, webstorm

I have tried all option given like setting `JAVA_HOME`, `ANDROID_HOME` and Path but none of working. I am still getting same error.

Comment: what OS are you on? Where is the android executable located? Seems it can't be found in your $PATH/$ANDRIOD_PATH.

Comment: @JBNizer your comment is ignorant of the fact that Android SDK is needed in WebStorm when you are trying to set up Cordova apps environment with Ionic Framework.